# onPress function for DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, onpress

I have created a DrawerNavigator in my react native app which looks like this.
I just dont like the default header that react- native gives. So I wanna access it through an icon. I guess also using the onPress condition

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

// importing of all screens


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerContent = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={CategoryStack}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Interest Recieved" component={InterestRecieved} />
   
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MainStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>

      <Stack.Screen
        name="Loading"
        component={Loading}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
  
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainStack;
```

How do I open it using an onPress of an icon?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

React navigation `useNavigation` hook expose drawer actions -  `toggleDrawer`,`openDrawer` and `closeDrawer` event handlers which you can use to open or close drawer.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const ToggleDrawer = () => {
  const { toggleDrawer,closeDrawer,openDrawer } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={toggleDrawer}>{/** Add your Icon Here */}</Pressable>
  );
};
```

You can check in-depth [drawer example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Getting%20started%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.11.15%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.12.9%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.3.19%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.3.19%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.9.8%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.14.9%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fdrawer-open-close-toggle.js)

Answer (score 0):

In the header options you can customize the header and add for example an icon on the top left side like this.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        title: 'ScreenName',
        
        headerLeft: () => (
            <View style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} >
                    {*INSERT ICON HERE*}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        ),
    })

})
```